# Updating a column in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm just learning and I don't understand how to update a separate column in the table, I use MySQL. The table is called card, I want to update the pincode column.
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE COLUMN pincode = strPincodeNew' at line 1

```
 public void newPC1(String strPincodeNew, String cardNumber) {
        try {
            Connection c = Database.connection();

            Statement stmt11 = c.createStatement();


            String sql12="ALTER TABLE card UPDATE COLUMN pincode = strPincodeNew";

            stmt11.executeUpdate(sql12);
```

```
while (pincodeNew>=....) {
                                    System.out.println("\n\n==== Enter a new PIN code ====\n");
                                    pincodeNew = scanner.nextInt();
                                }
                                String strPincodeNew = String.valueOf(pincodeNew);
                                operation.newPC1(strPincodeNew, cardNumber);
                                System.out.println("PIN code successfully changed");
```

Rewrote different commands

Comment: Your intention is to change the definition of the table? Or is it to change the pincode to a new value?

Comment: @g00se
I want to change the pin code in the table. At first I wrote: 
String sql 11 = "UPDATE pin code SET pin code = strPincodeNew" 
but as I understand it, JDBC does not understand what I want, and at first it wrote that the tab table does not exist. 
So I wrote: String sql12="ALTER TABLE card UPDATE COLUMN pin code = strPincodeNew".
Well, in general, I want to change the pin code to a new value

Comment: @isaace
while (pincodeNew>=....) {
                                    System.out.println("\n\n==== Enter a new PIN code ====\n");
                                    pincodeNew = scanner.nextInt();
                                }
                                String strPincodeNew = String.valueOf(pincodeNew);
                                operation.newPC1(strPincodeNew, cardNumber);
                                System.out.println("PIN code successfully changed");

Comment: Let's start with the table definition. Do you know how to use mysql client?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. You need to correct the card number column name where necessary:

```
    public void newPC1(String strPincodeNew, String cardNumber) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection c = Database.connection();
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE card SET pincode = ? WHERE card_number = ?")) {
            ps.setString(1, strPincodeNew);
            ps.setString(2, cardNumber);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't have time for a friendly conversation until it turns out that I'm writing in SET pin code = 'strPincodeNew'

``` This is the whole code: String sql13="UPDATE card SET pincode = 'strPincodeNew' WHERE card_number = '" + cardNumber + "'";``` 

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfr0O.jpg

Comment: You absolutely *don't* want to be doing that. In addition to being open to potential injection attacks, your code is difficult to read and error-prone. You should use `PreparedStatement` as I showed

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to change a *column* in a *row*. So you need to select both.

Likely you want to do something like

```
UPDATE card SET pincode = '1234' WHERE card_id = 'abcdef';
```

You need to have one row (via an `INSERT` statement) in the table, before you can update something.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have time for a friendly conversation until it turns out that I'm writing in SET pin code = 'strPincodeNew'

```
 This is the whole code: String sql13="UPDATE card SET pincode = 'strPincodeNew' WHERE card_number = '" + cardNumber + "'";
``` 

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfr0O.jpg